# connecting an web api controller to an html page to display an image

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am new to the web development world and the steps of creating an interaction between a web api and an html page

I found [this tutorial](http://goo.gl/5tmCd) but I really don t know how to make a connection to my controller

I have a function that takes a bunch of parameters (strings , ints , bools , etc...)and it returns an Image (type `Bitmap`) . the function should take these parameters from the HTML page

so I need to do something similar to this in a javascript function:

```
function()
{
      img = mywebapifunction(x,y,z,...);
}
```

how can I connect the controller to my page and how to write this function ?

EDIT :

I am using the following script (If I understand correctly):

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You would use an ajax request to communicate (in the background) with the server.

Comment: @AlbertoPonte Thank you for your response! can you show me a sample code ? As I said I am really new to web development world

Comment: What is the name of the script that will be receiving the request?  What parameters does it needs to fulfill its request?

Comment: forgive me, I assumed you were using straight javascript/jQuery, I did not notice that ASP was involved.  I do not know ASP so this may not be relevant.

Comment: @AlbertoPonte no worries :)

Comment: So you have an ASP.NET Web API controller, and you want to call it using Javascript?

Comment: @Snixtor  YES that s basically what I need to do

Comment: The article you linked has some great starting advice under the section *"Calling the Web API with Javascript and jQuery"* Have you tried the jQuery `$.getJSON` method yet? What difficulty have you had using it? Error messages? Unexpected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was even easier than I thought!!!

the code should be as follows :

```
function()
{
      $("#img").attr("src", myapicallstring);
}
```

where

myapicallstring calls the api function